# Wrap text inside table based on screen width

Tags: css, responsive

I want to wrap a single-line text inside a table considering the screen width resize. The table occupy 100% of the screen width and I want to wrap the text in one line only (wrapping with ellipsis if it overflow the content width) once the window is resized. I could only achieve a text wrap when specifying a fixed width in pixels. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4vo7p58c/5

The problem is that without a fixed `width` on `td` element, it doesn't wrap the text, and once I horizontally resize the window, the row breaks into two lines instead wrapping the text to fit the screen width

Comment: Remove `  white-space: nowrap;` from the `td`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there with you code,

> `td` is by default `table-cell` element which is typically different from `inline-block` or `block`.

If you want to use `ellipsis` value then you should have a width for `td` this will make sure the content remains overflow and use either `display:block/inline-block;` for your cause, it works for both.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid red;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1pt solid #4C4C4C;
  border-right: 1pt solid #4C4C4C;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 20%;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="External">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Element</th>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Second Element</th>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Third Element</th>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Fourth Element</th>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Manjuboyz. I wasn't clear enough on my question (I've edited it now) but I want to avoid line break, but wrap the text with ellipsis if it overflow the content width.

Comment: Thanks for the update. On this new code, the `td` element is constrained to have 60% of the available width. The problem is that I need that it always fit 100% of the available width, wrapping the text with ellipsis if it still have content to show. Also, If i resize the window on JSFiddle to be lower than 60%, the text overflows the red box instead wrapping.

Comment: Ok, I got what you're trying to say, but I feel both statements are contradicting here, To hide the excess content you have to give some specific width for the `td` and on decreasing the screen size what do you want to happen? mean the content should go somewhere right, but in your case you don't want to wrap then what should happen?

Comment: I think new code solved both of your questions now! check it. Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/r581obtL/25/

Comment: Thank you very much @Manjuboyz! This solution worked like a charm!